# How do I change data in cell, comparing it with a value of another cell inside the same row?

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services

In my MS SQL server report, I need to change text style in cell according to the value of another cell in tablix (values are in the same row). I can't understand how to specify exact cells or rows in report expressions.

I've tried to add another tablix column (in the same group) and use it as an argument in expression for another column, but it worked for every cell in that column:

```
=Iif(Fields!Smth.Value Like "Smthng", "Bold", "ExtraBold")
```

Comment: You've specified this in the textbox font weight property?

Comment: Yes. Again, the problem is that I can't understand how to get specify rows via expressions.

Comment: can you show your report design including any row of column groups that you have, also the names of the relevant cell and your expected results. It's hard to give an answer without more detail.

Comment: I guess my next question is... does SSRS actually display a difference between bold and extra bold?  I'm not 100% sure that it does...  [Do you see any difference?](https://imgur.com/Z4s6IaY) Might be better to try bold vs not bold to test the expression because from what I can see, this expression should work.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to use `CASE` statement in your query:

```
select case when Fields!Smth='Smthng' then 'Bold' else 'ExtraBold' end from YOURTABLE
```